# Loading symbols that begin with an underscore

Tags: winapi, nim-lang

My google-fu's weak regarding this issue…  (edit/spoiler: `_` isn't the issue after all, see below)

To provide some context, I'm developing a tiny *portable* program using Nim. At some time, I wanted to use `getch()` on win32 (using an old windows XP)…

The Nim doc says:

> `proc getch(): char {.raises: [], tags: [].}`
>   Read a single character from the terminal, blocking until it is entered. The character is not printed to the terminal. This is not available for Windows.

… so eventually I used:

```
proc getch(): cint {.importc: "_getch", header: "<conio.h>".}
```

and that works fine for my needs. Later however, I tried using the `dynlib` pragma instead:

```
proc getch(): cint {.importc, dynlib: "msvcrt.dll".}
```

That fails at runtime: `could not import: getch`. No magic there, the symbol should start with an underscore! But `_getch` or even `` `_getch` `` are illegal in Nim.

(Note: there was allegedly a `getch` in the CRT but MS tells it's deprecated and we should use `_getch` instead.)

To make sure, I tried the same thing with a libc symbol Nim doesn't know about:

```
proc atoi(s: cstring): cint {.importc: "atoi", header: "<stdlib.h>".}
```

and

```
proc atoi(s: cstring): cint {.importc, dynlib: "msvcrt.dll".}
```

That works in both cases; `atoi` (obviously) doesn't begin with `_`.

I can do with the `header` pragma for now in this case, but that's a general issue I'm probably going to face again, hence my question:

**How do I get to import symbols that begin with `_` with the `dynlib`pragma?**

The best would be an additional pragma in the same `{. .}`, as opposed to a flag when invoking the toolchain, but at this point any hint is welcome. I'm looking for a solution that doesn't rely on external libs or other languages.

Cheers.

(Nim 0.13.0)

**EDIT:** (in case others run in the same trouble)

OK, so I was chasing the wrong problem. As commented by @flyx, `importc: "symbol"` can be used with `dynlib` in the same way as in the `header`. The thing is, I had tried before and dismissed this combination for the wrong reasons (since Nim is still under heavy development, sometimes I have to take a guess… unlucky this time).

In fact:

```
proc getch(): cint {.importc: "_getch", dynlib: "msvcrt.dll".}
proc kbhit(): cint {.importc: "_kbhit", dynlib: "msvcrt.dll".}
```

didn't work for me. Not at compile time but at run time.

That still doesn't: `_getch` doesn't return until I Ctrl-C it (perhaps that's why it's not implemented on Windows in the first place!) and with a loop on `_kbhit` I need to kill the task.

```
proc getch(): cint {.importc: "_getch", header: "<conio.h>".}
proc kbhit(): cint {.importc: "_kbhit", header: "<conio.h>".}
```

DO work.

But because now I tested successfully

```
proc atoi64(s: cstring): clonglong {.importc: "_atoi64", dynlib: "msvcrt.dll".}
```

I can tell that **the underscore is a non-issue**.

Comment: `proc getch(): cint {.importc: "_getch", dynlib: "msvcrt.dll".}` does not work?

Comment: @flyx You're right, apparently. I had tried that, and there was an error, so I must have been confused and wrongfully dismissed it as an illegal pragma combination… shame on me. I might have been confused because `_getch` (and some other _xxxx functions) doesn't seem to behave properly, though… I'm investigating, maybe that's a calling convention issue. However what you wrote works for `_atoi64`.

Comment: @flyx. Thx for your help. I'll call it a day. I'll mark your comment as the answer if you make it an answer. Or I'll do it myself later, but you deserve the points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
proc getch(): cint {.importc: "_getch", dynlib: "msvcrt.dll".}
```